# Can't select a bound attribute in Angular

Tags: css, angular, css-selectors

I have a custom progress bar in angular.  I'd like to bind to have a selector for the `[value]`.  However if I bind the attribute in Angular it is no longer possible to select.

`<progress-bar value="50">` works

`<progress-bar [value]="value">` fails

The attribute doesn't exist in the second case it's just there as one of the ng-reflect-* attributes.  Is this expected behavior?

component:

```
ProgressBar {
    private currentValue;
    @Input() set value(value: number) { this.currentValue = value; }
    get value() { return this.currentValue; }
...
}
```

scss:

```
progress-bar {
    display: block;
    height: 4px;
    width: 100%;

    // determinate
    &[value] {
        background: map_get($color-palette, progress-bar-background);

        .progress {
            height: 100%;
            background: map_get($color-palette, progress-bar-color);

            animation: none;
            transform-origin: top left;
            transition: transform 250ms ease;
        }
    }

    // indeterminate
    &:not([value]) {
        background: transparent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a guess, but "value" might be reserved by the Component class. Have you tried something like "myValue"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding--property-), you can use [attribute binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#attribute-binding):

```
<progress-bar [attr.value]="value">
```

```
export class ProgressBar {

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {}

  get value() {
    const element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    return element.getAttribute("value");
  }
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b4azky) for a demo.

---

A simpler solution is to set a class conditionally on the component with `HostBinding`:

```
export class ProgressBar {

  private currentValue;

  @Input()
  get value() { return this.currentValue; }
  set value(value: number) { this.currentValue = value; }

  @HostBinding("class.has-value") get hasValue(): boolean {
    return !!this.currentValue;
  }
}
```

and to apply the styling according to the class selector:

```
progress-bar {
  ...
  &.has-value { 
    ...
  }
  &:not(.has-value) { 
    ...
  }
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zsxtzk) for a demo.

Comment: That works, but is that the only way?  It seems to me this would be a common use-case.  `[attr.value]` is a little silly to have to explain downstream, lol.  Not to mention the hackiness of the lookup and attribute conversion.

Comment: I added another (simpler) solution, which uses class styling.

Comment: Yah the second solution is what I'm doing, but I'm just amazed that Angular clobbers the attributes breaking css capability.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a one way property binding between a object and method. Remove your getter and setter methods. They are kinda of useless since javascript doesn't have real private properties or methods.

```
ProgressBar {
    @Input() public value: number
...
}
```

Comment: still end up with just `ng-reflect-value` and :not([value]) is the match.